# how to change the widget from footer to sidebar

Tags: wordpress

i have the wordpress site and the widget is on the footer. how can i change it to sidebar.

http://screencast.com/t/fTBlNmZXCt8i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme should allow dropping to sidebar - which then you'd drag the widget to the sidebar.  Are you building a new theme and asking how to add a sidebar which allows widgets to be dropped onto it?

Comment: No. i am using the following theme. BirdSITE 1.02 by Sysbird

Comment: I don't know that theme off the top.  It does have side bars?